# Cake php Missing helper, working on local but not on remote

Tags: php, linux, windows, cakephp

Faced this issue and none of the solutions mentioned online actually helped:
Using Cake php all my project was working perfectly fine on a local windows machine but not working on a linux server and I was presented with this error:

```
Missing Helper
Error: HTMLHelper could not be found.

Error: Create the class HTMLHelper below in file: app/View/Helper/HTMLHelper.php

<?php
class HTMLHelper extends AppHelper {

}
```

Eventually I found out that I wasn't missing any helpers but the issue was in the ctp file and the different ways Linux and Windows read that file. I will write the answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way this was solved was by changing these:

```
$this->HTML->script
$this->html->script
```

to this:

```
$this->Html->script
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a same problem and still with erros. In my case i nedded to change

`$this->form` to `$this->Form`

`$this->url` to `$this->Url`

and some elements was named with error.

**Linux is case sensitive** and some methods needs named like Cake docs, even windows works